# Django_Facebook regarding AUTH_USER_MODEL

Tags: django, facebook, authentication

I've been having difficulty understanding the Django_facebook documentation, especially when it says to put AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'django_facebook.FacebookCustomUser'. My web app uses the normal Django user registration, but with this, it eliminates my original Django user registration when I syncdb everything. Any ideas about what I should do? I want my web app to use Django's user registration system as well as Facebook's user API.